# Event Computed property issue

Tags: svelte

I'm learning Svelte and I would like to know why the click event doesn't work on this example. I get an error message:

> TypeError: each_value is undefined'

https://svelte.technology/repl?version=1.56.1&gist=798be31e79dfbf363a9f7e497557acfb

```html
<p><input bind:value=search></p>

{{#each categories.filter(predicate) as category}}
  <!-- the click event should work, right? -->
    <button on:click='console.log(category)'>{{category}}</button>
{{/each}}

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                search: '',
                categories: [
                    'animal',
                    'vegetable',
                    'mineral'
                ]
            }
        },
      computed: {
            predicate: search => {
                search = search.toLowerCase();
                return word => word.startsWith(search);
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a bug introduced in 1.56 — if you [change the version in the URL to 1.55](https://svelte.technology/repl?version=1.55.1&gist=798be31e79dfbf363a9f7e497557acfb), it works. We'll get it fixed. Thanks!